# What is the difference between Poisson Regression and Log-linear Models in terms of their usage and which should I use?

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, log-linear

I'm currently analyzing a **data set** from an experiment, where participants could give one of three types of answers: 1) Correct, 2) incorrect-congruent, 3) incorrect-incongruent. The priming participants where exposed to beforehand also varied along these lines, being either a) congruent, b) incongruent or c) no priming.

My **hypothesis** is now, that congruent priming increases congruent answers, but that incongruent priming will not increase incongruent answers. This should show in an interaction between prime type (a and b) and answer type. Note that answers are not independent from each other (if the answer is type a, it cannot simultaneously be type b or c).

According to my research, the **appropriate analysis** would be a Poisson Regression, but my mentor suggested a Log-Linear Model. When looking this up on the internet, it seems that these analyses are sometimes used interchangeably.

My **Question(s)**: Are they the same? If not, do they apply to the same data? And then, which one would be the correct analysis for my current data set?

Comment: From description of your problem I don't see how Poisson regression relates to it... First, you do not to have count data, but rather categorical variables. Second, it seems to be rather hypothesis-testing than modelling problem. Could you describe your data and problem in greater detail?

Comment: It is count data, since I count the event of an answer belonging to category a, b or c. When I collapse the data, I will therefore have a contingency table with answer types as the row titles and prime types as column headers.

Comment: So you assume that counts of answers are independent of each other..? Such assumption is inconsistent with your data since each participant can give "one of three types of answers".

Comment: This is, what I stated in my description above: " Note that answers are not independent from each other (if the answer is type a, it cannot simultaneously be type b or c)."

Comment: But in your model you assume that they are independent!

Comment: What do you mean? Poisson Regression is not the appropriate analysis?

Comment: Your description is unclear so I do not want to jump into conclusions, but from what I gather, yes, it seems that Poisson regression is inappopriate in here. Please edit your question to add more details (e.g. data example), so it is more clear what you want to do and what is your data.

Comment: Your data are really multinomial. The log linear model is a Poisson GLM adapted for analyzing multi-way contingency tables. I suspect (but can't tell for sure) that your data can be represented as a multi-way contingency table, so you could use the log linear model. There are examples on this site, if you search.

Comment: The Loglinear model (a subset of Poisson GLM) does not assume independence, it's better to say that it explains [independence relations](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/102) in multi-way contingency tables. Categorical variables can be represented as count data, and this type of inferential modelling can be more informative than simple hypothesis testing. However, in the case of two-way tables, Poisson regression, log-linear models, and simple hypothesis testing will all have essentially the same same result.

Answer (score 1):

Log-linear Poisson regression (with interactions) on the counts in a higher dimensional frequency table is a standard way to analyze associations between categorical variables. So in your setting, the two terms are interchangable.

In your two-dimensional setting, you can also use less general methods (Cramér's V, percentages, chisquared-test; depending on what you are interested).